# Pass parameter to $apply in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to refer to a scope variable from $apply function in AgularJs?

```
<div myAttr="getMe(param)">hoverMe</div>

$scope.getMe = function(myParam) {alert(myParam);};
$scope.param = 2;
$scope.$apply(attrs.myAttr) //undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. It's exactly the same way you proposed.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'This is the value';
  $scope.change = function(val) {
    $scope.result = val;
  }
}
```

Programmatically, it's just a `scope.$apply('change(value)')`.

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/n7LK7/). Double check if you're not applying to a different `$scope`, like `$rootScope`.